# How do I get visual studio 2017 to see my phone, a Samsung Galaxy J1 (2016)?

Tags: android, visual-studio, samsung-galaxy

I am new to app development, though an experienced software developer.

I have developed a small app in Visual Studio community (free) 2017 with Xamarin,
and run it successfully in the emulator. I do not know how to deploy it to the phone.

I tried to follow the instructions in
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/
including setting development mode on the phone, but I could not find the drivers
for the phone listed on the Samsung website. Instead I connected the phone to the PC by USB, and
updated the drivers by Windows seasrching on the internet.

When I load my project into Visual Studio 2017, it does not see the phone.

Can someone please advise what I need to do to make this work correctly?

Comment: Well I don't use Xamarin Studio but before you should install [ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) for your phone then connect your phone to desktop/laptop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I attempt to install the ADB driver as suggested above, by 'update drivers', Windows reports that the latest driver is already installed. So I am no further forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by upgrading to Windows 10. This may not have been necessary, but deploying to the phone now works.